# JAVA - How to access parent frame component in action listener?

Tags: java, jframe

this is my code

This code gives me a frame with text displayed inside it.
I may need to modify the text as necessary, and then there are two buttons. One pushes the code further, the other one closes the application.
What I want to do is add listener to okButt, within the createOverviewButtonsPanel method, that would retrieve the value of txtMenuOverview in order to pass it further is this even possible?

MenuOverviewFrame class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MenuOverviewFrame extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5908534022988507381L;
private static final Font FONT = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 16);
private static final Font MENU_FONT = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED,Font.BOLD,14);
private static final Color BLUE_STEEL = new Color(70, 107, 176);
private static final Dimension INITIAL_SIZE = new Dimension(500, 300);
private static final Dimension MINIMUM_SIZE = new Dimension(275, 150);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        MenuOverviewFrame frame = new MenuOverviewFrame("Test test\ntest\ntest");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}

public MenuOverviewFrame(String menuOutput) {
    super("Daily Menu");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setSize(INITIAL_SIZE); // The initial frame size
    setMinimumSize(MINIMUM_SIZE);

    JTextArea txtMenuOverview = new JTextArea(menuOutput);
    txtMenuOverview.setFont(MENU_FONT);
    JScrollPane taScroll = new JScrollPane(txtMenuOverview);
    add(taScroll);

    JPanel overviewButtonsPanel = createOverviewButtonsPanel();
    overviewButtonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(overviewButtonsPanel.getPreferredSize().width, overviewButtonsPanel.getPreferredSize().height + 30));
    getContentPane().add(overviewButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // at the center
}

private JPanel createOverviewButtonsPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    //panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 1));
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,20);
    panel.setBackground(BLUE_STEEL);

    JButton okButt = new JButton("Send menu");
    JButton koButt = new JButton("Abort mission");

    panel.add(okButt,gbc);
    panel.add(koButt);
    okButt.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    return panel;
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Since your class `MenuOverviewFrame` extends JFrame, you already have access. Use `this` in order to refer the frame. Example, this.dispose() will dispose the frame.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I want to create the action listeners inside the createOverviewButtonsPanel method

Comment: well this is kind of basic java knowledge. When you are in an anonymous class, in order to refer the outer class, you use OuterClass.this. So in your case, inside action listener, `MenuOverviewFrame.this.dispose();`

Comment: Right! Thanks. This works perfectly now. I am using get method to retrieve the string.